# connection time out in curl

Tags: php, curl

I have problem with my curl code. I got connection timeout when the time I run it. It almost a 2 days now looking for an answer. I try searching it in google and stackoverflow, but I failed to get the answer.

**here's the code**

```
$url = "https://152.155.155.155"; <-- dummy ip address
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response);
```

The client provides ip address to connect to there server. What is the reason why I always get connection timeout? Is it necessary to provide a header and postfield?
Please help me guys. thank in advance for your help.

Comment: May be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304924/curl-connect-timed-out This thread helps you.

Comment: I try their code but the result is empty. I guess when I reach 5 seconds.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the website using a browser?

Comment: @YSU yes i try it. I was thinking if there is a firewall on their server. Honestly I don't know about server side.

Comment: so were you able to connect using the browser or did it fail?

Comment: the same result connect() time out.

Comment: Then there is no problem with your code. There is some hop on the route to the server that is dropping the connection.

Comment: @YSU sorry late reply. I guess you're right. I'm now trying to explain this to my team lead and I'm waiting for the reply of our client now. Thanks anyway for your reply. Hoping not my code is the problem.