# Error 28 timed out! PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to add information into the rest web service at a particular port number: 8999. On localhost, it is working fine but on the live server, it gives the following error:

> cURL Error (28): connect() timed out!

Here is the code

```
$ch = curl_init('http://int.otono-me.com:8999/api/customers/new'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8999);                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    "Content-Type: application/json",                                                                                
    "X-Auth-Token: " . $_SESSION["Token"]
));                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
if($curl_errno > 0) {
    echo "cURL Error ($curl_errno): $curl_error\n";
} else {
    echo "Successful\n";
}
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Any suggestion on what needs to be done?

Comment: Try increasing the timeout value

Comment: i think the problem is same listed here, you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304924/curl-connect-timed-out

Comment: @Pradeep Patel: I think that might be the issue I am not sure...what is strange is my case is that I am able to fetch data from the web service on my live server, but when I am trying to either enter or update any information into the port: 8999 of that web service, it is giving me this error

Answer (score 1):

Either you have a proxy on the live system,
or a firewall in between.

Ask your local sysop for changes regarding firewall.

You are also missing a `'`:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://int.otono-me.com:8999/api/customers/new'); 
//       -------^
```

Comment: Hello DanFromGermany....the firewall has been disabled.....but I will have to check if it has to do with the proxy on the live system or if there is any issue with user privileges...

Answer (score 0):

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://int.otono-me.com:8999/api/customers/new");
```

also your link is not answering

Comment: please explain your answer

Comment: Good answers *explain* as well as provide code. Consider updating your answer to include an explanation about how this code works and why it is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement your PORT in your URL. Send separatelly URL and PORT:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://int.otono-me.com/api/customers/new");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 8999);
```