# Download failed. cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I am developing website in WordPress and I used reflex theme. there are some required plugin of this theme example- reflex layers extension.

I am trying to install this plugin, but I am facing below error:

> Download failed. cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304924/curl-connect-timed-out

Answer (score 0):

I has a problem with one Wordpress plugin and couldn't login or reset the password. Website had several plugins so I simply created a new folder called HALT in the plugin directory and moved the entire lot of plugins into it.

Was able to reset the password and finally login afterwards.

Once in, I saw Wordpress core had an update, clicked to update and bam. The error that you're seeing.

Went on duckduckgo, Doogled the error, while around the same time flew into the open cpanel tab and moved the plugins back out of the HALT folder I'd created.

Went into Wordpress admin panel, hit the update buttons. And end of story.

In short, I'm sure there's a plugin just messing around. Do a consistency check and determine if all the Wordpress files, and plugins are valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code-snippet to increase request timeout of the HTTP request

```
add_filter('http_request_timeout','http_request_timeout_callback');
function http_request_timeout_callback() {
    return 100;    
}
```